# TypeError: get_object() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create the object only if there is no user is present in the table or else update the field. My implementation is :

```
class UserMobileViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = UserMobileDevice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserMobileSerializer

    def get_user(self, id):
        try:
            UserMobileDevice.objects.get(user=id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None



    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        myModel = None
        id = request.data.get("user")  #id = 52 pk = 2
        print(id)
        if id:
            myModel=self.get_user(id)
            print(myModel)
        if myModel:
            return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

My table schema is as :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "token": "f5a906ec934425d00fc40e3b260eca2c48965d0a",
        "device_model": "Samsung J6",
        "os": "Android 9",
        "os_version": "9",
        "created_at": "2019-09-12T03:36:11.630303Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-12T03:36:13.724340Z",
        "user": 2
    },
  ....
]
```

I am getting error as :

> TypeError: get_object() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I am very new to DRF, Not sure how i will get the object from the id. Any suggestion will be of great help!!

Comment: How is `get_object` defined?

Comment: I have not defined anywhere get_object

Comment: @DYZ Can you please help me how to define get_object if its not pre defined method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Got the view/viewset stuff mixed up.

You can define your own to do this.

`get_object()` takes no parameters, and gets the value indicated in the URL when you use a `router` to create your routes.  A typical url would look like `/users/30/`, and `get_object()` would return `User(id=30)`.

```
def get_user(self, id):
    # returns null if no match
    return User.objects.filter(pk=id).first() 

def get_user(self, id):
    # catch exception and manually return none
    try:
        User.objects.get(pk=id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I have solved that issue, But i started getting `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` And I believe somewhere its repeating it

Comment: My main objective is if user exist in that table then it should update or else create [Note : user_id is not pk]. I have updated my question please have a look!!!

Comment: Your `create` method calls itself (the last line).  You want to use `super().create`.  Honestly, there are a few issues here.  There are alternate approaches which might help, but would take a bit to explain in full.  Essentially: 1) override get_serializer_class to return a different serializer for create vs. list 2) the create serializer has a `user` field which validates as an int, and then you can either write a custom `def validate_user` function which will create it, or override the viewsets `perform_create` function and do it manually there, passing it to serializer as a kwarg.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew I have solved my issue by using  create_or_update. But I will look in this approach tomorrow.